# What is a file with extension .a?

Tags: c, gcc, shared-libraries

I downloaded this: https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-c-driver

And now I'm trying to use it inside my C program, but I don't know what to do with the generated .a files. What are they? I couldn't find any information, not even in the GCC manual.

And I built it like so:

```
  scons --c99
```

Also, can I use [C99](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C99) libraries with my C89 program?

Comment: Possible duplicate of *[What's the difference between .so, .la and .a library files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12237282/whats-the-difference-between-so-la-and-a-library-files)*.

Answer (score 118, accepted):

`.a` files are [static](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Library_%28computing%29#Static_libraries) libraries typically generated by the [archive tool](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ar_(Unix)).  You usually include the header files associated with that static library and then link to the library when you are compiling.

Comment: I thought the .so files are the library files. Do I need to use both then?

Comment: @Blub: there are both static and shared libraries. In Linux, .a is a static library (archive), while .so is a shared library (shared object).

Comment: You can see the contents of a `.a` static library by using `ar tv foo.a`. It's usually a collection of `.o` object files.

Comment: how are they called for easy googling?

Comment: They are called Archive Files

Comment: You can use the `ar` command in macOS to extract, remove, modify files and create .a archives.

Answer (score 40):

`.a` files are created with the `ar` utility, and they are libraries. To use it with `gcc`, collect all `.a files` in a `lib/` folder and then link with `-L lib/` and `-l<name of specific library>`.

Collection of all .a files into `lib/` is optional. Doing so makes for better looking directories with nice separation of code and libraries, IMHO.

Comment: What exactly is the "name of library", the name of .a file or the name of the folder that included .a file, or others?

Comment: I tried both, they were all returned errors.