# Xlsx IO library (from sourceforge) issue

Tags: c++, c, io, xlsx

[xlsx io from sourceforge](https://sourceforge.net/projects/xlsxio/)

Anyone know how to actually use this library?

I took the time to download it and include it with a project.

The problem is, when I try to compile, if I attempt to call any of the library's functions, I get the dreaded linking error: "unresolved symbols".

I'm using Visual Studio Express 2013.

To make this more clear, here's some sample code I've tried (that creates the linker error).

```
#include "xlsxio_read.h"


int main(void){
    xlsxioreader x = xlsxioread_open("input.xlsx");
}
```

And before anyone asks the standard inane questions, Yes I put the header files and their dll's into the appropriate directories before trying to include or use anything.

Comment: OK, you put the headers (which are required for compilation) and DLLs (which are required for running) in the proper places. But did you put the `lib` files (which are required for linking) somewhere accessible, and did you set up your program's linker properties to link these in?

Comment: IOW, did you look at the [FAQ on "Unresolved symbol"](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12573816/1782465)?

Comment: I didn't see any .lib files.... Unless that's what those .a files were for but I've never seen a .lib file with such an extension. Edit: I'm a turd. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5965171/what-is-a-file-with-extension-a Yep. .a files are libraries XD

Comment: Edit: But now how to link .a with visual studio... XD

Comment: Nevermind, it was pretty easy.