# How can i add a static library of type .a to a visual studio project?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, include, package, static-libraries

I am trying to use [MathGL](http://mathgl.sourceforge.net/doc_en/index.html) in my project. When i go through the package contents i can only find .a static library files, how can i use those to include that library in my Visual Studio project?

I have tried to include all the .a files by going to Project Properties->Configuration Properties->Linker->Input

and link all the .a files using "additional dependencies". But then i still get a ton of errors when i include the mgl.h file.

I guess my question is: is the way to use a library in your program is to include the needed .a files? and if yes, what is the correct way to do it?

Comment: Have you seen this link: http://mathgl.sourceforge.net/doc_en/Download.html#Download ? Here you can download the MataGL library for Linux or Windows

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a file with extension .a?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5965171/what-is-a-file-with-extension-a)

Comment: In a Windows application you cannot.

Comment: @JorgeOmarMedra Yes, i downloaded that, but there aren't any .lib files in the package, just .a files.

Comment: @Lanting I did checkout the link, but it didn't help me with figuring out how to link the library in visual studio.

Comment: Are you saying that there is no way to use .a libraries in Visual Studio? @JesperJuhl

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According with the documentation of MathGL, the libraries are into the directory **mathgl/lib**, and **they are dinamic link libraries(dlls)**:

[image]

The same documentation says:

> Use a precompiled binary. There are binaries for MinGW (platform Win32). For
>   a precompiled variant one needs only to unpack the archive to the location of the
>   Chapter 1: Overview 3
>   compiler (i.e. **mathgl/lib in mingw/lib, mathgl/include in mingw/include and so on**)
>   or in arbitrary other folder and setup paths in compiler. By default, precompiled
>   versions include the support of GSL (www.gsl.org) and PNG. So, one needs to have
>   these libraries installed on system (it can be found, for example, at http://gnuwin32.
>   sourceforge.net/packages.html).

So, you need to link the Dll instead of a static library, check this asnwer to see how to link a dll: [Linking dll in Visual Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7845886/linking-dll-in-visual-studio)