# What does the file ending .a and .la mean?

Tags: binary, fpic, nlopt

I know that file endings are not important for the functionality of binaries on linux, but I would like to know the meaning of two file endings I encountered from [Nlopt](https://nlopt.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)

libnlopt.a and libnlopt.la any idea what these endings mean? I found [this resource](https://kb.iu.edu/d/affo), but it didn't have the mentioned endings listed.

I'm wondering because I'm trying to figure out if the libnlopt.a was built with -fPIC or not, because following the first answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1340402/how-can-i-tell-with-something-like-objdump-if-an-object-file-has-been-built-wi) the library was not built with -fPIC, this is strange because when building I added the option to ./configure(provided by nlopt) --with-pic. So I was wondering if the file ending means I have to go a different route to find out if it was built with -fPIC or not?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a file with extension .a?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5965171/what-is-a-file-with-extension-a)

Comment: Can't I as the author of the question close it myself? I found a duplicate but still there are 5votes required to close